# Getting related many-to-one objects with a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have three related tables in PostgreSQL:

- `objects` - top-level table, that has an ID and a name.
- `object_events` - a related table, that has a foreign key to `objects`
- `object_aux_data` - a table that uses many-to-one relationship with `object_event`

Some example data:

- `objects`:

  - id: 1, name: test_object
- `object_events`

  - id: 1, object_id: 1
  - id: 2, object_id: 1
- `object_aux_data`

  - object_event: 1, name: foo, value: foo_val
  - object_event: 1, name: bar, value: bar_val
  - object_event: 2, name: foo, value: foo_val2
  - object_event: 2, name: baz, value: baz_val

It is easy to get a list of `object_events` that are related to the `test_object`, but I'd like to also attach to the results some of the `objec_aux_data`. So the output results will look like this:

| object.name | object_event.id | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_object | 1 | foo_val | bar_val |
| test_object | 2 | foo_val2 |  |

Note, that the `foo` has value for all `object_event` but `bar` only for the first one. `baz` is not taken into account in this case.

Is it possible to get this data with a single query, or should I have a separate query for each `object_event`?

Example schema:

```sql
create table objects(
  id int,
  name varchar
);

create table object_events(
  id int,
  object_id int
);

create table object_aux_data(
  object_event int,
  name varchar,
  value varchar
);

insert into objects values (1,'test_object');
insert into object_events values (1,1),(2,1);
insert into object_aux_data values (1,'foo','foo_val'),(1,'bar','bar_val'),(2,'foo','foo_val2'),(2,'baz','baz_val');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple join ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uHJUYXgTVGyY3PiscxTZwT/1))

```
with bar as (
  select oe.id, oad.value
  from object_events oe join object_aux_data oad on oad.object_event = oe.id 
  where oad.name = 'bar'
),
foo as (
  select oe.id,oad.value 
  from object_events oe join object_aux_data oad on oad.object_event = oe.id 
  where oad.name = 'foo')
select 
    o.name,oe.id,coalesce(foo.value,''),coalesce(bar.value,'')
from
    objects o join object_events oe on o.id = oe.object_id
    left join foo on foo.id = oe.id
    left join bar on bar.id = oe.id
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not entirely what I meant - my example was too simplistic. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful - however, I wonder if it's possible to simplify it? In my real case it's not just two values but around 6 of them and the base query is also a bit more complex, so repeating it would make it very hard to read and quite error-prone for future modifications. Can it be somehow simplified, or it is as simple as it gets?